# Install the virtual box guest additions Debian wheezy

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I am trying to install the virtual box guest additions and it mounts  successfully on to Debian wheezy. When I open this mounted drive I see a message in nautilus in the top right saying

> "the medium has been detected as unix software   ***_*__*_*__*_*__**_Open Autorun prompt"

When I click on that I get the message:

> Cannot find the autorun program

Comment: please could you try to describe preciselyu what and how you're trying to doing things ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open a `terminal`

```
su
cd /mount/yourcd
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

The problem you faced is that there's no autorun on the CD and it's a very good thing, because autoruns can be dangerous.

Answer (score 19):

Alternative: Install the guest additions from the official Debian repository. That way, they'll be updated whenever you run a system update:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Update:

If this package can't be found, edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and replace `main` with `main contrib non-free`, then run `sudo apt-get update` and run the install command. Of course, this can also be done using graphical tools.

Also, as mentioned in the comments section, **dkms** may have to be installed as well.

Comment: +1 yay! This works on Debian 8 as well!! (I sent several unsuccessful hours trying to get this to work). For this to work for me, I also ran: `sudo apt-get dkms` and I had also updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to include the other Debian repositories (i.e. editing each Debian-related line from `main` to instead say -> `main contrib non-free`)

Comment: Thank you user2533809, I have added this to my answer. Looks like the [package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/virtualbox-guest-additions) is in the non-free archive.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dkms` should be `sudo apt-get install dkms`

Answer (score 3):

1. Login as root (issue `su` at a terminal or `sudo`);
2. Update your APT database with `apt-get update`;
3. Install the latest security updates with `apt-get upgrade`;
4. Install required packages with `apt-get install build-essential module-assistant`;
5. Configure your system for building kernel modules by running `m-a prepare`;
6. Click on Install Guest Additions… from the Devices menu, then run mount `/media/cdrom`.
7. Run `sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, and follow the instructions on screen.

Comment: It's really helpful. I've installed Debian 8.6 without any problem.